# options-general.php page displays different sitename, home compared to wp_options table

Tags: options, configuration

I was assuming that `options-general.php` page should display `wp_options` table contents. I understand that this is a naive interpretation of the implementation.

**Question:** can someone explain the relationship between these two entities and why my old domain name is still present in `wp_options` table however it is correct when navigating to `options-general.php`. Thanks.